# SQL Union/Merge two rows DB2

Tags: sql, db2, union

In my current result are  following lines:

```
item|val1|val2
9999|0   |50
9999|50  |0
```

How can i merge them into:

```
9999|50  |50
```

I cant do subquery based on item, the results of each query are providing a list of items

```
SQL:############################################
select item, sum(val1), 0 as dummy from itemdata
union
select item, 0 as dummy, sum(val2) from itemdata2
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use:

```
SELECT item, sum(val1), sum(val2)
FROM table
GROUP BY item;
```

If you are using multiple tables:

```
SELECT item, sum(val1), sum(val2)
FROM (SELECT item, val1, 0 AS val2 FROM itemdata
      UNION ALL
      SELECT item, 0, val2 FROM itemdata2) sub
GROUP BY item;
```

Comment: sorry i forgot that the sql is on different tables, i have changed that above